# How to make Grid with round corner in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to make my Grid with round corner in my WPF project.
And due to some reason, I have to use ViewBox and hence to make it more difficult.
My code is as below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Green"
    Width="500" Height="300">

<Grid x:Name="gridTotal">
    <Viewbox x:Name="vb">
        <Grid Width="500" Height="300">
            <Image x:Name="BlackMaskImage" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Button Width="100" Height="100">
                
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

I tries some method, like this:
[How can I make a rounded-corners form in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654634/how-can-i-make-a-rounded-corners-form-in-wpf)

But not work for my case.

**More：**

In my code, there are two Grid. But for me, the final appearance of the window has 4 round corner is OK. That is I don't care which Grid is fabricated.

I tried to change the `gridTotal` to a Border, and that border can own round corner. But its content is still a rectangle with sharp right angle.

In UWP, a Grid can apply Style with setter to set its CornerRadius, but in WPF I cannot do so.

Comment: Your example has two Grid.
Which one are you writing about?
Grid is just a panel.
Only Border has rounded corners.
Accordingly, to get rounded corners, you need to either place the Grid in the Border, or vice versa - the Border in the Grid.

Comment: @EldHasp Thank you for your reply! I update my main post to answer your questions. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify any region breakdown in the Grid.
Use Border instead.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="{x:Null}"
    Width="500" Height="300">

    <Border x:Name="gridTotal" CornerRadius="20"
            Background="Green">
            <Grid Width="500" Height="300">
                <Image x:Name="BlackMaskImage" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                <Button Width="100" Height="100">

                </Button>
            </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thx for posting this, EldHasp.. keeps me off the google search !